# Что случилось с valueForKeyPath в Swift 3?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3

Делал по одному видео уроку парс JSON. У автора все вышло успешно, но у него Swift 2.

Дело в строке с `valueForKeyPath`:

```
let responseDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
self.newsArray = responseDictionary.valueForKeyPath("data") as! [AnyObject]
```

Ошибка:

```
Value of type 'Any' has no member 'valueForKeyPath'
```

Как тогда перейти в JSON в нужную "секцию" по ключу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разница в обработке JSON между swift 2 и 3 колоссальная. Думаю Вам поможет официальная документация: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Выдержка:

```
let input = "{\"data\":{\"a\":\"b\"}}"
let data = input.data(using: .utf8)!

let responseDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:Any]

if let nestedDictionary = responseDictionary["data"] as? [String: Any] {
    print(nestedDictionary["a"])
}
```

Comment: Я уже все перепробовал. Конкретно на ваш ответ: https://goo.gl/2mvZrT. Всегда одинаковые ошибки, которые я не могу решить.

Comment: `as? [String: Any]` показан для примера, я не могу знать структуру JSON которую Вы пытаетесь прочитать. Для себя всю головную боль я исключаю используя https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: Подправил пример, чтобы его можно было использовать "как есть" скопировав в Playground.

Comment: Честно, ни фига мне это не помогло :( Я не знаю что делать уже... Никогда мне еще не было так тяжело распарсить чертов JSON.

Comment: Вот код: https://goo.gl/cNpP8E

Comment: `let responseDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(...) as! [String:Any]` - первый шаг, на выходе Dictonary из которого можно читать значения